# Find corresponding column and row data based on data from another cell in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Ok, so I have an excel file with a few tables like the one in the image and at the link below.

[Screenshot of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYggm.jpg)
[image]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/967glpkyfjfb6iy/Test.xlsx?dl=0

What I am trying to do is be able to enter a value that's in the **D2:N21** range and have it return the corresponding value of a cell in columns **B** & **D** and the date from **Row 1** and have them display in cells **B26**, **C26** & **D26** respectively.

I've tried using **INDEX MATCH** formulas but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm assuming that I am missing something. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if there are duplicates in D2:N21, what value it should consider then?

Answer (score 2):

This *can* be done without using any VBA. However, it requires more than just the Lookup/Reference functions as those only work in one dimension (as do most other functions).

`SUMPRODUCT()` is one function that does work with two dimensional arrays (which can be generated using just a simple comparison).

The solution requires just the two following formulas:

**Formula 1** Entered in `B26` and ctrl-entered/filled/copy-pasted into `B26:C26`:

```dart
=IF(ISERROR($D26),NA(),INDEX(B:B,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($D$2:$N$21=$A26)*(ROW($D$2:$N$21))))))
```

**Formula 2** Entered in `D26`:

```dart
=INDEX($1:$1,COLUMN($D$2:$N$21)-1+MATCH($A26,INDEX($D$2:$N$21,MAX(1,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($D$2:$N$21=A26)*(ROW($D$2:$N$21))))-ROW($D$2:$N$21)+1),1):INDEX($D$2:$N$21,MAX(1,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($D$2:$N$21=A26)*(ROW($D$2:$N$21))))-ROW($D$2:$N$21)+1),COLUMNS($D$2:$N$21)),0))
```

The prettified version of formula 2 is:

```dart
=
INDEX(
  ($1:$1),
  COLUMN($D$2:$N$21)-1
  +MATCH(
    $A26,
    INDEX(
      $D$2:$N$21,
      MAX(1,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($D$2:$N$21=A26)*(ROW($D$2:$N$21))))-ROW($D$2:$N$21)+1),
      1
    )
    :INDEX(
      $D$2:$N$21,
      MAX(1,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($D$2:$N$21=A26)*(ROW($D$2:$N$21))))-ROW($D$2:$N$21)+1),
      COLUMNS($D$2:$N$21)
    ),
    0
  )
)
```

Note that if the dollar amounts in the table were unique, a less complex formula could be used. Since you have not specified what you would like to do when duplicates are found, I have written the simplest formula that still works when they are found.

This formula just so happens to extract the left-most matching value in the bottom-most row that contains a match. It can be modified to return certain specific alternative values.

The following formula can be used to detect if duplicates exist in the table for the value entered in `A26`, if some notification/action is required:

```dart
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((D2:N21=A26)*(ROW(D2:N21))))<>SUMPRODUCT(SUM((D2:N21=A26)*(ROW(D2:N21))))
```

For the case of unique values, the `MAX()` function in formula 1 would no longer required, of course, and the simplified formula 2 would be:

```dart
=INDEX($1:$1,IFERROR(1/(1/(SUMPRODUCT(($D$2:$N$21=A26)*(COLUMN($D$2:$N$21))))),NA()))
```

**Notes:**

- The prettified formula actually works if entered.
- The brackets around `($1:$1)` in the prettified version are required to force the `$1:$1` to remain on its own line.
- Although I have chosen to display the `#N/A` error if the entered dollar amount cannot be found, this can be changed to anything else.

Answer (score -1):

I think all the lookup/reference functions search on columns or rows. I would use "custom functions", which are VBA functions that go in a Module. You would need 3, one for B26, C26, and D26.  Here is one for D26 (Date).  In D26 you would have "=zDate(A26)".  The Module:

```
Option Explicit

Function zDate$(param$)
  Dim icol&, searchRange As Range, cellRange As Range
  Set searchRange = Range("D2:N21")
  Set cellRange = searchRange.Find(param, , xlValues, xlWhole)
  icol = cellRange.Column ' column of found cell
  zDate = Cells(1, icol) ' returns date
End Function
```

EDIT:  What an amazing answer from @robinCTS. I am going to buy the accompanying book. I was moved to create

```
=INDEX(A1:N21,1,MAX(SUMPRODUCT((D2:N21=A26)*(COLUMN(D2:N21)) )))
```

but it doesn't check for dups and I don't understand the format "$bbbnn.nn". In mine, A26 would have to include the "$" and spaces. Thanks

Comment: Looks like you figured out the simpler formula quite well. The only issue with it is for the case where the value in `A26` can't be found. Your formula returns the date in column `D`, causing the other formulas to trigger a circular reference warning (or not, if iterative calculations were allowed) and `B26:C26` would retain their previous search values. And, of course, it would return incorrect/mismatched results for dups, as you implied. Your formula actually *does* work without entering the `$` and spaces, as those are just there due to the Accounting number format used for the data cells.